# PHP: Echo value of selected item from a dependable dropdown menu

Tags: php

I am currently working with a Dependable dropdown menu that functions with the help of jQuery and PHP. The values are being pulled of MySQL database. Is there away to php echo the selected value of a dependable drop down menu?

[EXAMPLE](http://www.ssdtutorials.com/tutorials/series/dependable-dropdown.html)

**HTML/PHP**

```
<form action="" method="post">

        <select name="gender" id="gender" class="update">
            <option value="">Select one</option>
            <?php if (!empty($list)) { ?>
                <?php foreach($list as $row) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                        <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
                    </option>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>

        <select name="category" id="category" class="update"
            disabled="disabled">
            <option value="">----</option>
        </select>

        <select name="colour" id="colour" class="update"
            disabled="disabled">
            <option value="">----</option>
        </select>

</form>
```

Comment: Please explain this more `How can echo the selected Item from a dependable drop down menu?`

Comment: @Adnan sorry for not being clear, I have edited the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but still not clear enough. Do you want PHP to per-determine the selected item so when the page loads an item will be already selected? Or do you want that AFTER the user has selected something it will go to PHP and then echoed back to the browser?

Comment: just look at the demo, I think he wants to update the second dropdown with values based on the selected item from the first dropdown.

Comment: @krike, oh really?! If that's what he wants then there's no point in making this question, the demo already has the code and the videos already provide the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add jquery.js.
your html code

```
    <select name="gender" id="gender" class="update">
        <option value="">Select one</option>
        <?php if (!empty($list)) { ?>
            <?php foreach($list as $row) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
                </option>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>

    <select name="category" id="category" class="update" disabled="disabled">
        <option value="">----</option>
    </select>

    <select name="colour" id="colour" class="update" disabled="disabled">
        <option value="">----</option>
    </select>
        //jquery code for source list
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#gender').change(function() {
              if ($(this).val()!='') {
                $("#category").load("postfile.php",{gender_id: $(this).val()});
                $("#category").removeAttr('disabled');
              }
            });
            //code on change of sel_source
            $('#category').change(function() {
              if ($(this).val()!='') {
                $("#colour").load("postfile.php",{category_id: $(this).val()});
                $("#colour").removeAttr('disabled');
              }

            });
        });
    </script> 



//postfile.php
//your mysql connection other things goes here
//code for category
$objDb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'ur_username', 'ur_password');
if(isset($_REQUEST['gender_id']) && !empty($_REQUEST['gender_id'])) {

           $sql = "SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `master` = ?";
    $statement = $objDb->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute(array($_REQUEST['gender_id']));
    $list = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(!empty($list)) {
        $output = '<option value="">Select</option>';
        foreach($list as $row) {              
                $output .= '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
        }
    } else {
        $output = '<option value="">Select</option>';
    }
    echo $output;
} 
//code for color

if(isset($_REQUEST['category_id']) && !empty($_REQUEST['category_id'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `master` = ?";
    $statement = $objDb->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute(array($_REQUEST['category_id']));
    $list = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     if(!empty($list)) {
        $output = '<option value="">Select</option>';
        foreach($list as $row) {          
                $output .= '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
        }
    } else {
        $output = '<option value="">Select</option>';
    }
    echo $output;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for this. Although one thing i see that you are using `['gender_id']` and `['category_id']` but the MySQL table is set up different with only this fields `id` , `master_id`, `name`. You can see here in the video: [Database SETUP](http://www.ssdtutorials.com/tutorials/title/populating-records.html)

Comment: I am passing gender_id and category_id from our html to php, they are not thd table field.You have to specify table field in your select query.

Comment: thank you, I tried everything possible. Can you send me a working source to my emai? I would really appreciate it my friend.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to write a JavaScript function that retrieves the selected value or option from the first HTML select field. This function commonly writes out a new URL path to the current page with the addition of some concatonated Get Variables:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
getSelectedOptionValue() {
// create some variables to store your know values such as URL path and document
var myPath = " put the URL path to the current document here ";
var currentPage = "currentPage.php";
// get the values of any necessary select fields
var carMake = document.getElementById("carMake").value;

// write out the final URL with the Get Method variables you want using concatnitation
var getMethodURL = myPath + currentPage + "?carMake='" + carMake + "'";

// function refreshes page using the function made URL
window.location.replace( getMethodURL );
}
</script>
```

Since the second select field is dependent on the first you have to assume that the user is going to make a selection from the first choice of options. This means that the function that retrieves the value of the primary select field must run in response to a change in the fields selection. For example

```
<select name="carMake" id="carMake" onchange="getSelectedOptionValue();">
```

Depending on how you have set up your DB, you may want either the value of the option tag or the string presented to the user between the option tags...this is up to you keeping in mind how you may re-query the information if your original record set hasn't already pulled up the necessary info to write the second set of select option tags.

To write out the second select field using php simply repeat the while loop you have used for the first. This time replace your SQL statement with a new one using a variable in which you have stored the value retrieved from the new URL using the get method

```
<?php

// here I am using the more generic request method although you could use the get as well
$carMake = $_REQUEST['carMake'];

sql_secondSelectField = "SELECT * FROM tbl_carModels WHERE carMake = $carMake";

// Run new query and repeat similar while loop used to write your first select field ?>
```

Comment: You can also call this function using AJAX if you do not want to leave the page to refresh the get variables by reloading the page, but this adds another few steps of complexity.

Comment: You can also add an if statement to your php while loop that will add the selected state to an option tag by comparing the current iteration of records to the get method variables posted in the new URL created by the JavaScript function. This will keep the option the user selected before the page was reloaded using the window.location method.